# cakephp3 how to check there is no linked data before delete

Tags: cakephp-3.x

I have 2 tables: `table1` and `table2`

There are linked with :

```
table1 hasmany table2
```

I do not want to delete row from table1 if there is linked data in table2

I guess I have to use `$rules->addDelete` to do that ?

What is the best check ?

Do I have to build a

`select from table2 where table1_id=$id` ?